# Facebook email account settings for evolution?

Tags: 11.04, evolution, email, settings, facebook

I have a @facebook.com email id...how do I setup evolution using that?

Comment: is it even possible to use the facebook email like that?

Comment: @Roland I could give it a try, if I know the server and other settings for it!

Comment: I read somewhere that that wasn't the plan on facebook's end, so it might not be possible to use the email except through a web interface.

Comment: @Roland got it..so it can be accessed only from fb!thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19031):

> How do I set up a free @facebook.com
>   email address? To set up a free
>   @facebook.com address, go to your
>   Messages view and click the "Claim
>   your Facebook email" link.
>
> Your email address will match your
>   public username, for example:
>
> Profile: facebook.com/username Email:
>   username@facebook.com
>
> If you don’t have a username yet, you
>   can choose one when you create your
>   email address.
>
> Once you set up your email address,
>   people can email you using any
>   traditional email system (e.g.,
>   Hotmail, Yahoo or Gmail), and the
>   emails will be delivered to your
>   Facebook Messages. When you send
>   messages to external email addresses,
>   the emails will be formatted to look
>   like Facebook messages, including your
>   name, your profile picture and your
>   message.

This seems to be the official information from Facebook but it points to **receive** email from traditional email systems, not to **sending** from elsewhere but inside of the Facebook web.

I hope you find a solution for this.

Good luck!

Comment: @Geppevettvs thx for the info!

Comment: Good one. This is what I was trying to say ^^.

Comment: I wonder if there is any pop, imap or smtp server?